# Añadir valores a array PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un array tal que así y necesito añadir a `$array['referencia']` otro registro como el del array, por así decirlo un `$array['referencia'][2]`

```
$array['referencia'] = (array =>( 'Codigo' => 'x', 'Numero' => 'y', 'Stock' => '12312' ))
```

Comment: Hola Pavlo. ¿Y qué has intentado? ¿Errores o problemas?  Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de la pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinceramente, no sé si lo que has escrito es código PHP válido.

Lo que tienes que hacer es que `$array['referencia']` sea un array de elementos. Así podrías añadir más elementos a placer:

```
$elemento1 = array(
  'Codigo' => 'x',
  'Numero' => 'y',
  'Stock' => '12312'
);
$array['referencia'] = array(
  $elemento1
);
$elemento2 = array( /* código, número, stock */ );
$array['referencia'][] = $elemento2;
```